# Soundcard not working / not detecting on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 18.04, soundcard

Lenovo N21 Chromebook. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, running an xubuntu desktop.
When I've had to go back to ChromeOS, the speakers and audio work perfectly fine.

I've looked for about two hours, tried unmuting everything in pavucontrol / alsamixer, to no avail.

All HDMI outputs are unplugged, and all I see is Dummy Output, or the audio doesn't work in the first place.

Running aplay -l and lspci | grep -i audio give this:

(Aplay)

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 0: Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: chtmax98090 [chtmax98090], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lspci:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx 
Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
```

Both audios when lspci are ran are highlighted in red.

Any help is appricated in advance. Tyty.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem and i had tried everything but couldn't able to resolved the problem then i figured out that it wasn't the driver causing the problem it was keyring password that i had provided so if you tried everything ,try to reset your keyring password to blank

**Go to System/Preferences/Password and Encryption keys, right click the appropriate folder and click Change Password. Put in your old password and leave the new one blank. its worked for me , try it may works for you.**